# What does GO#4HQ mean on the DD214 Service Record?

Tags: united-states, military-records, world-war-2

On my fathers [DD214 Certificate of Release or Discharge from Active Duty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DD_Form_214), in the section Decorations and citations, it lists Purple Heart with 3 oak clusters GO#4HQ.

What does that mean?